# Using combinatorial reasoning to show $n!=\binom{n}{0}D_n+\binom{n}{1}D_{n-1}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}D_0$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, factorial

How can one use combinatorial reasoning to show that

$$n!=\dbinom{n}{0}D_n+\dbinom{n}{1}D_{n-1}+\dbinom{n}{2}D_{n-2}+....+\dbinom{n}{n-1}D_1+\dbinom{n}{n}D_0$$

Now $D$ stands for deranged which is a permutation when a number is not its "natural position." For example $\{2,3,1\}$ or $\{3,1,2\}$.

The formula for derangement is
$$D_m=m!\left(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\dots+(-1)^m\frac{1}{m!}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each term ${n \choose k}D_k$ represents choosing $k$ elements to be fixed in a permutation, then making sure none of the other elements is fixed.  The sum is over all numbers of elements that can be fixed, so all permutations are accounted for.  You can even delete one term as $D_1=0$

Comment: I see so on the right side you chose a k term which is fixed and the rest of you n-k are permuted for each sum

Comment: Exactly.  Going the other way, given a permutation, you find the fixed elements and that tells you which term on the right it is part of.

Comment: and D1=0 because you are already choosing out of n all possible n and that is zero so therefore D0 is also zero?

Comment: No, $D_1=0$ because if you fix $n-1$ of the objects, there is only one space for the last one, which is prohibited.  $D_0=1$.  You have to count the identity permutation where every element is fixed.

Comment: Yes that makes sense because a factorial the last place is not a zero but a like 5! is 5x4x3x2X1